# Get a specific number of rows and place in new column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that has over 300k rows. I need to break them up into groups of 10k and export them into a csv file. I'm thinking the easiest way is to make each column 10k rows. I'm working on a test code that's only using 18 rows. I'm trying to loop through the entire set and place every 3 rows in a new column. Somehow I'm totally lost. This is what I have so far and my output:

```
rows = []
for j in range(len(new_zones)):
    for i in (0,3):
        rows.append(new_zones) 
rows_df = pd.concat(rows, axis=1)
```

and my output:

```
Bin ID  Dropzone    Bin ID  Dropzone    Bin ID  Dropzone    Bin ID  Dropzone    Bin ID  Dropzone    ... Bin ID  Dropzone    Bin ID  Dropzone    Bin ID  Dropzone    Bin ID  Dropzone    Bin ID  Dropzone
7   P2DP352 dz_02   P2DP352 dz_02   P2DP352 dz_02   P2DP352 dz_02   P2DP352 dz_02   ... P2DP352 dz_02   P2DP352 dz_02   P2DP352 dz_02   P2DP352 dz_02   P2DP352 dz_02
8   P2DP353 dz_02   P2DP353 dz_02   P2DP353 dz_02   P2DP353 dz_02   P2DP353 dz_02   ... P2DP353 dz_02   P2DP353 dz_02   P2DP353 dz_02   P2DP353 dz_02   P2DP353 dz_02
9   P2DP354 dz_02   P2DP354 dz_02   P2DP354 dz_02   P2DP354 dz_02   P2DP354 dz_02   ... P2DP354 dz_02   P2DP354 dz_02   P2DP354 dz_02   P2DP354 dz_02   P2DP354 dz_02
10  P2DP355 dz_02   P2DP355 dz_02   P2DP355 dz_02   P2DP355 dz_02   P2DP355 dz_02   ... P2DP355 dz_02   P2DP355 dz_02   P2DP355 dz_02   P2DP355 dz_02   P2DP355 dz_02
11  P2DP356 dz_03   P2DP356 dz_03   P2DP356 dz_03   P2DP356 dz_03   P2DP356 dz_03   ... P2DP356 dz_03   P2DP356 dz_03   P2DP356 dz_03   P2DP356 dz_03   P2DP356 dz_03
5 rows × 72 columns
```

I'm wanting 3 rows in each column.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example of input and matching expected output (small dataframes with simple dummy data)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that (please notice the path format):

```
def split_df(df, k_rows, path):
    count = 0
    df_index = 0
    while count <= len(df.index):
        if count == 0:
            new_df = df.iloc[:k_rows, :]
            new_df.to_csv(path+str(df_index)+".csv")
        else:
            new_df = df.iloc[count:count+k_rows, :]
            new_df.to_csv(path+str(df_index)+".csv")
        count += k_rows
        df_index += 1


split_df(df_test, 3, "./split_csv/df_")
```

Edit - You can try this:

```
def split_df(df, k_rows, path):
    list_df = []
    count = 0
    while count <= len(df.index):
        if count == 0:
            new_df = df.iloc[:k_rows, :]
            list_df.append(new_df)
        else:
            new_df = df.iloc[count:count+k_rows, :]
            list_df.append(new_df)
        count += k_rows
    final_df = pd.concat(list_df, axis=1)
    for col in final_df.columns:
        final_df = final_df.replace(col, np.nan).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()))
    final_df.to_csv(path)

split_df(df_test, 3, "./split_csv/final_df.csv")
```

Comment: That's almost what I'm wanting. Is there a way to keep it all on the same csv instead of different ones?

Comment: can you specify what is the desired output? (example) because i don't understand why do you split it and after that merging it?

Comment: I have a csv file that has two columns and a whole bunch of rows. I'm looking for a way to take a set number of those rows and move them into two new columns. the output above look right, the only problem is I can't get the length of row correct. Like above, I was trying to get rows of 3, and kept getting five. I want all the columns to be side by side, in groups of a specific number of rows. Then export to one csv. Or would this be easier to do in excel? I just don't know how to do it in excel either.

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: please accept my answer :) @Laura